# Node not finding Less module

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, less

I am trying to install Node and Less on Ubuntu 12.1. Installing appears to work ok and I can see there is a Less folder created when I install Less using "sudo npm g install less" in:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules

However when I run "lessc -v" I get the below:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/lessc:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure: did you run `sudo npm g install less` or `sudo npm -g install less`?

Comment: And make sure that /usr/local/lib/node_modules is on your PATH

Comment: @gustavohenke - I ran -g, was that wrong?

Comment: @Benoir - can you explain that more, do I have to be in the right dir when installing with NPM?

Comment: I'm wrong -- try https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/45

Comment: Dang - progress. So now I can run lessc -v - and have 1.3.3 BUT only as SUDO, this was achieved by using the ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/ .node_libraries command at the link provided by @Benoir, does anybody know how to change my setup so I don't need Sudo to run less? Maybe that is another question...

Comment: I installed with `-g` and my nodejs can't find less still...

Answer (score 8):

You should create symlink to node modules directory into your home directory.

```
$ ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/ ~/.node_libraries
```

(if you installed node from source it'll be /usr/local/lib/node_modules)

Comment: Works for me as well. Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Modules installed in the "global scope" (which is what happens when you use `npm -g install` or install node modules from Ubuntu repositories, for example - `sudo apt-get install node-less`) are loaded by populating the `NODE_PATH` environment variable.

Packages installed from Ubuntu repositories handle this automatically, but if you install manually you have to set this yourself. In your case, you'd need to add the following command to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export NODE_PATH="$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

It works at my Ubuntu 13.04