# node.js through FastCGI/PHP: Error: Cannot find module 'less'

Tags: php, node.js, assetic

I installed node.js from sources (`./configure && make && make install`) under `/usr/local/bin/node`. Afterwards I installed the less compiler globally with `npm -g install less` under `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/`. So node and less are located under their default paths.

I am using `kriswallsmith/assetic` to compile my less files through PHP, therefore I adjusted path to `/usr/local/bin/node`. Everytime I run my script I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'less'`, I had the same behavior through command line. But I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945298/node-not-finding-less-module) (`ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ ~/.node_libraries`) to fix the problem and after this it worked out on command line. Through PHP the problem still persists - PHP is running through FastCGI with the same user I used on command line.

How can I fix this problem through FastCGI/PHP too?

Comment: You should be able to `npm link less` in your project directory and it will create a symlink to your global installation of `less`.

Comment: That makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor of assetic's LessFilter accepts an array of nodePaths. Adding `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` as a nodePath solves the problem.