# Is there a difference in node global module and an include in require()?

Tags: node.js, less

I have been trying to run a small js script in node. It has a statement `var less = require('less');`. I made sure that `node`, `npm`, and `less` are available globally. Despite, when I run `node` on my  `lessCompile.js`, I am getting a `'module not found'` error. Why?

Here is my command line sequence.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\node_tut>npm install -g less
C:\Users\stumma\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc -> C:\Users\stumma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc
less@2.0.0 C:\Users\stumma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less
├── graceful-fs@3.0.4
├── mime@1.2.11
├── promise@6.0.1 (asap@1.0.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── source-map@0.1.40 (amdefine@0.1.0)
└── request@2.47.0 (caseless@0.6.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, oauth-sign@0.4.0, stringstream@0.0.4, tunnel-agent@0.4
.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime-types@1.0.2, qs@2.3.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, tough-cookie@0.12.1, form-data@0.1.4, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.1.1, bl@0.9.3)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\node_tut>less
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\node_tut>node lessCompile.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\node_tut\lessCompile.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

### **ADD**: My lessCompile.js code:

```
var less = require('less');

less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', function (e, output) {
  console.log(output.css);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require()` works with global modules.

Add `C:\Users\stumma\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your Windows `PATH` environment variable.

This is were Node global modules are stored.  Currently you don't have this directory in the `PATH`.

After that run `npm include less` to make less available not only as command line executable, but also for `require`.

Comment: @SivaPrasadTumma Correct.  Node installer for Windows doesn't add path to the directory to Windows `PATH` environment variable.  You have to set it manually.

Comment: Okay I have looked in. My path already contains this. I have found similar question in linux platform [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945298/node-not-finding-less-module?rq=1)

Comment: @SivaPrasadTumma post your `lessCompile.js` source code

Comment: @SivaPrasadTumma Do `npm link less`.  It will make global module available not only for command line execution, but also for require.

Comment: Awesome.  I am marking yours as correct Answer. Thanks. Please update your answer to include this comment.